# How to make reference to image path in maven swing project?

Tags: java, image, maven, path, reference

I am Using Windows 10, Apache NetBeans, maven swing project;

maven project structure:

```
|-- projectname
    |-- Source Packages
    |   |--package1
    |   |--package2
    |   |--resources
    |   |   |--images
    |   |   |   |--image.png
```

Though NetBeans displays nested packages/folders like this `resources.images`

[image: project structure]

Inside NetBeans, When I right-click on `image.png` then click `Properties` then click (`All Files` <kbd>...</kbd>) it gives me this path:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectname\src\main\java\resources\images\image.png
```

How to reference image path?

I tried many paths, also many answers from this site, but non solved my problem. The output always gives `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
java.net.URL u = getClass().getResource("/resources/images/image.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(u);
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Image and Text", icon, JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: So, "resources" for maven go in the `{project folder}/src/main/resources` folder.  From within your code, you don't need to reference `resources`, just sub folders (ie `/images/tick.png`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I also tied this exact path with the preceding slash, but same error.

Comment: But based on the directory structure you've provided, it's in the wrong directory for maven, in fact, your directory structure is wrong for maven generally

Comment: @MadProgrammer I uploaded a photo, if this is not proper location, then how to properly create a `resources` directory in maven.

Comment: You might want to have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69308166/netbeans-12x-mavan-include-and-load-embedded-resources